# How to delete MSSQL database using sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server

I have multiple databases created by POCO approach of website building and I want to delete those. However I get error.

### Command

`sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -q "drop database aspnet-ORData-20120910180110"`

### Error

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server MY-PC\SQLEXPRESS, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '-'.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -Q "drop database [aspnet-ORData-20120910123456]"
```

Note the square brackets around the database name.  Without them the dashes ("-") are seen as tokens instead of part of the database name and the parser will want to do math.    The command parser interprets anything inside square brackets as a literal.

Comment: Note that if you want it to run the command and exit, use a capital -Q instead of lowercase -q.